# Ansible recursively grant read-only access to files

Tags: ansible, file-permissions, ansible-2.x

I've a dir `/read-only-others-group` where users in `others` group should have read-only access to all files, recursively. I tried with [file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9_ja/modules/file_module.html) module:

```
- name: Ensure /read-only-others-group directory exists and gives read-only access to others group
  file:
    path: /read-only-others-group
    state: directory
    recurse: yes
    owner: someuser
    group: somegroup
    mode: "0754"
```

This permission doesn't allow users in others group `ls` or `cat` a file or `cd` into the directory or any under it.

It may be solved with shell module like:

```
find /read-only-others-group -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755
find /read-only-others-group -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 754
```

Is there a be a better, idempotent solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: **"*Users in other groups should have read-only access*"**

A: Use [symbolic mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameter-mode)

```yaml
    mode: "o-w"
```